# How to start my excel headers from a row(10th row is where my data starts)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

How do I move my headers to the top from row 9 when creating a dataframe using pandas. I don't want to remove data from row 0-8. Here is a screenshot of the data I have and my data starts after row 9 where you see the actual headers.

I have used drop to remove the rows but I would like to explore the option of keeping the data and then executing the same operations. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Where do you want to keep the data from rows `0-8` before or after the data following the actual header? Also its better if you include the sample of your data instead of posting the pics.

Comment: @Shubham Sharma. I tried to include the image but since this is my first post I was only able to post the pic until I reach 10 points. Sorry about that. I was forced to do it.

Regarding your question, I just don't want to touch it and for my ease, I would like to take it out while performing my operations on this data.

Comment: @vow7779 Please Include your code showing what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved using the below changes. 
'skiprows=9' has skipped the rows that I wanted to ignore and 
'header=0' has changed the first row after skipping to become the header

> df = pd.read_excel('orig.xlsx', header=0, skiprows=9)

Answer (score 0):

Setting [header](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to the **8** while calling *read_excel* should work. 
And then use [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html?highlight=iloc#pandas.DataFrame.iloc) to remove data from 1-9 rows in your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to get it done by doing this

df = pd.read_excel('orig.xlsx', header=0, skiprows=9)